# Verify instanceof when i use a static class under another one

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instanceof

I have a class under a class like :

```
public class Class0 implements Class1{

    static class Class2 extends Class3 {
        ...
    }

}
```

In another class I want to verify if my object is an instance of Class2, using `obj instanceof Class2`.

So when I print the class of my object I obtain :

```
class Class0$Class2
```

My question is, how do I use `instanceof` in this case? because when I try `Class0.??!` I dont obtain `Class0.Class2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `instanceof Class0.Class2`. But make sure that the class is visible. You declared the class with the package visibility.
The name `Class0$Class2` is the name of your class in the compiled code. Normally you don't refer to it.

Comment: I have a responnnnse ! i must to make my class visible  `public`. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to make sure an object is of specific class you need to use `Object.getClass()` method, not `instanceof` operator.

Because the operator will simply return true if an given object is an instance of a given class, and this would be true for all the parent classes and interfaces in your object's hierarchy.